# How to create a bug using zoho API via postman?

Tags: api, post, postman, zoho

I am working on `Zoho API`. Using postman I want to create/issue a bug in the system. For this, I am looking into [Zoho Bug API](https://www.zoho.com/projects/help/rest-api/bugs-api.html#alink3). For creating a bug below are the request parameters list in the link.

**Create a Bug**

```
POST  /portal/[PORTALID]/projects/[PROJECTID]/bugs/
```

**Creates a bug.**

**Request Parameters**

```
title*              String   Name of the bug.

description         String   Description of the bug.

assignee            Long     Assignee for the bug.

flag                String   Bug flag must be Internal or External.

classification_id   Long     Classification ID of the project.

milestone_id        Long     Milestone ID of the project.

due_date            String   [MM-DD-YYYY]    Due date of the bug.

module_id           Long     Module ID of the project.

severity_id         Long     Severity ID of the project.

reproducible_id     Long     Reproducible ID of the project.

affectedmile_id     Long     Milestone ID of the project.

bug_followers       Long    Follower ID of the user.

uploaddoc           File     The maximum size to upload a file is 128 MB.

Custom Fields
     
CHAR1 - CHAR12      String  Any text type of custom fields with string or picklist values.

LONG1 - LONG4       Long    Numeric type of custom field.

DATE1 - DATE4       String [MM -DD-YYYY]    Bug custom field in date format.
```

**Sample Response**

**Status: 201 Created**

**Content Type: application/json;charset=utf-8**

```
{
"bugs": [{
    "id": 170876000001851001,
    "key": "543",
    "project": {
        "id": 170876000000147021
    },
    "flag": "Internal",
    "title": "UI issue in Status text box",
    "reporter_id": "2060758",
    "reported_person": "Patricia Boyle",
    "created_time": "05-27-2014 08:38 AM",
    "created_time_long": 1401188920000,
    "assignee_name": "Not Assigned",
    "classification": {
        "id": 170876000000133041,
        "type": "Feature(New)"
    },
    "severity": {
        "id": 170876000000065005,
        "type": "Major"
    },
    "status": {
        "id": 170876000001077429,
        "type": "known limitation"
    },
    "closed": false,
    "reproducible": {
        "id": 170876000000133005,
        "type": "Always"
    },
    "module": {
        "id": 170876000000494013,
        "name": "ERP Phase I"
    },
    "link": {
        "self": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/2063927/projects/
                    170876000000147021/bugs/170876000001851001/"
        },
        "timesheet": {
            "url": "https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/2063927/projects/
                    170876000000147021/bugs/170876000001851001/logs/"
        }
    }
}]
}
```

**What I am doing**

**My request param**

```
https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/[PORTALID]/projects/[PROJECTID]/bugs/
```

**Key**

```
`Authorization:   myKey`
`Content Type: application/json`
```

**In body**

```
[{
   "title": "My First Bug",
   "description"      :"This is my first bug",
   "assignee" : "engr.usman" ,
   "flag": "internal",
   "classification_id": "1139168000000297069",
   "milestone_id": "",
   "due_date": "02-15-2018",
   "module_id" : "1139168000000019372",
   "severity_id" : "1139168000000007003",
   "reproducible_id" : "1139168000000017069",
   "status_id" :"1139168000000007045",
   "resolution": "",
   "affectedmile_id" : "",
   "customfields": [
            {
                "column_name": "LONG1",
                "label_name": "MSN#",
                "value": "2999000190"
            },
            {
                "column_name": "CHAR1",
                "label_name": "Circle-Division-SubDivision",
                "value": "Hyderabad - Latifabad - Tando Jam"
            },
            {
                "column_name": "CHAR3",
                "label_name": "LCD Indication",
                "value": "S7"
            },
            {
                "column_name": "CHAR2",
                "label_name": "Reference #",
                "value": "28371430034961U"
            }
],
"uploaddoc" : [""]
}]
```

**Response**

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 6831,
    "message": "Input Parameter Missing"
 }
}
```

**Update 1**

So just for testing it again. I have tried to send only mandatory and by default fields.

```
[{
   "title": "My First Bug",
   "flag": "internal",
   "classification_id": "1139168000000297069",
   "module_id" : "1139168000000019372",
   "severity_id" : "1139168000000007003",
   "customfields": [
         
            {
                "column_name": "CHAR2",
                "label_name": "Reference #",
                "value": "28371430034961U"
            }
]

}]
```

But again I am getting same error `Input Parameter Missing`

I don't know why this error is generating. As there is no method of sending a request in the link.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `title` is the only thing with an * next to it, does this mean it’s required. Have tried just sending a request with that and then adding each property one by one? Does the `uploaddoc` need to be sent if it’s empty?

Comment: @DannyDainton yes the `title`is mandatory. In custom fields `reference number` is also mandatory and `module_id`,`severity_id`,`flag` they are auto-generated fields. Also, I have tried not to send `uploaddoc` but still getting the error

Comment: Seems like it’s a commonly run into problem not helped by the poor documentation - https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/problem-when-creating-message-using-api

Comment: Are you sure that you have to send it as a JSON body rather than a set of query string parameters?

Comment: @DannyDainton I would try it, but can you please tell me how to pass the array as a query string ?

Comment: There is a `Params` button next to the `Send` button. Enter the values in here and this will construct the URL. Remember to remove the body data before sending.

Comment: Cool. You may want to close out your question if that worked.